# How to print given rhombus in attached image with same logic in java or any other language

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, logic

I have tried:

[image]

but not getting close, unable to get the relation between rows and columns to run the loop.`

```java
static void makeRhombus(int rows) {
    int i, j;
    int horizontal = 2 * rows;
    int vertical = rows + 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= vertical; i++) {
        /* Print trailing spaces */
        for (j = 1; j <= rows + 1 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        /* Print stars and center spaces */
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * rows; j++) {
            if (i != 1 && j == 1 || j == horizontal && i != 1) {
                System.out.print("/");
            } else if (i == vertical || i == 1) {
                System.out.print("_");
            } else if (i == vertical && j == 1) {
                System.out.print("/");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to use method [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) available in Java 11+, the ASCII rhombus may be drawn as follows:

```java
public static void printRhombus(int height) {
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(height) + "_".repeat(2 * height + 1));
    for (int i = height - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(i) + "/" + " ".repeat(2 * height) + "/");
    }
    System.out.println("/" + "_".repeat(2 * height) + "/");
}
```

Tests:

```java
printRhombus(2);
      
printRhombus(4);
```

Output

```
  _____
 /    /
/____/
    _________
   /        /
  /        /
 /        /
/________/
```

If this Java 11 method is not available/allowed, it may be replaced with another implementation to return repeated String, for example, using `String::join` available in Java 8+:

```java
private static String repeat(String pattern, int count) {
    return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(count, pattern));
}
```

Other ways to build a repeated string could be based on `StringBuilder` with a loop, or creating a String from a `char[]` filled with `N` characters using `Arrays.fill`, etc.